# How do I set up 3 monitors to a Mac Mini

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport

I have 3 monitors which I want to connect to my Mac Mini. 2 x HP and 1 x DELL. All 3 monitors have HDMI cables.

I already have a Thunderbolt adapter but it only has one HDMI port.
The adapter is plugged into the back of the mac using the thunderbolt connector.
I currently have one HP monitor connected directly to the mac mini, via HDMI cable and port.
I have the second HP monitor connected to the adapter via HDMI cable, using the adapter HDMI port.

I want to attach the third monitor now. Thought I could just buy a new adapter which would have 3 HDMI ports and connect that directly to the Mini, but can't find this type of adapter on the market. After reading some of the previous queries on here, not sure that will even work.
My third monitor is a DELL and has the following ports:
DP In
DP Out
HDMI (which is what i wanted to use as i already have cable)
3 x USB slots

My current Thunderbolt adapter has a VGA port but no VGA port on the DELL monitor so can't use that. It also has HDMI port, which I'm already using for another monitor, and then it has a DVI port.

So think I need to purchase a new adapter to connect all 3 monitors, but can't find one on the market. Is there a different solution? Any ideas?

Comment: or just buy a second thunderbolt to HDMI adapter. Please add the model of Mac Mini you have to your original question (EG Mac Mini late 2014) as port configurations often change from model to model

Comment: Hi Steve, thats what i'd like to do as all monitors came with HDMI cables.and thought that would be the easiest.. My mac mini model  is 2014

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% certain but think you probably need a Thunderbolt PCIx expansion enclosure with 3 or more slots so you can add something like a Blackmagic HDMI display card. There may be less expensive options available but I have been looking into adding more HDMI input ports to my MacPro and this was one of the few options I found.

Comment: Hi, that's great, thanks for the info, i will check this out

Answer (score 0):

You sad that the Dell display has DP IN and OUT. In that case you can daisy chain another display to the first one with a DP to HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that the 2014 Mini can push video to 3 displays. The specs say:

> Supports an HDMI-compatible device while using one Thunderbolt display
> or support for two Thunderbolt displays.

You've got an Intel integrated graphics unit 5000 series, which is fairly basic.

Thunderbolt 2 may limit your options for eGPUs, also.